# Resources for graph structure?

Tags: resources, graph-theory

I have  a problem related to graph.
I am not a computer science grad hence needed a some quick intro on what is graph and were can i read about graph and how to solve graph related problem in c++ or in general.

Comment: when you say "graph" do you mean a chart or a graph in the mathematical sense?

Comment: graph like cyclic directed,acyclic graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [boost graph library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) may be a starting point and give you some code for solving your graph related problems.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Graph problems](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/major_section/1.4.shtml) in the Stony Brook Algorithm Repository,
and [a cute lecture by Xavier Llora](http://www.slideshare.net/xllora/ge498eci-lecture-8-connectivity-everywhere-graph-theory-101).

Answer (score 0):

I would start by studying a few specific algorithms.  Dijkstra's algorithm and the graph closure algorithm are good places to start. Also most introductory computer science (eg. Data Structures) texts have a section on graphs.  I used [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072970545), mostly after I was already pretty comfortable with most of the material though.  It takes a pretty formal approach, so if your maths is strong you might like it.

The community might be able to give you better pointers if you mentioned something specific that you're trying to solve (if there is such a thing).

Answer (score -1):

This is a [very cool tool for representing graphs](http://mark-shepherd.com/blog/2006/12/03/recent-improvements-to-springgraph-graph-visualizer)